# Dynamic list view with data from edit text fields

Tags: android, listview

In my layout i want to have a dynamic list view and the list item contains a horizontal linear layout with three text views. I have  3 edit text fields, i want the three edit text fields data to be populated in list view when each time the data is entered in edit text fields

Comment: @Hasan you will get many more tutorials for custom listview just google it

Comment: so what is the issue ?